# CMMotionActivity returns with all activities 0

Tags: ios, core-motion

I'm getting activities through CMMotionActivity where all the listed activities are 0.

> 2016-07-21 11:54:57.807 myApp[245:12899] activity = CMMotionActivity @ 2366.054214, {startDate,2016-07-21 10:54:57 +0000, confidence,0, unknown,0, stationary,0, walking,0, running,0, automotive,0, cycling,0}

What does this mean? Why is it even providing an activity if there is no activity detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmmotionactivity):

> It is also possible for all of the properties to be set to false when the device is in motion but the movement does not correlate to walking, running, cycling or automotive travel.

So this is the real "unknown" state where CMMotionActivityManager doesn't know what you are doing.

The *unknown* property in the CMMotionActivity is set to true when the device is turned off, this usually​ happens when you are trying to query​ historical data.